# How do I get the brakes on my old car feeling like new?

Tags: brakes

Even after a fresh brake and rotor job, my brakes still don't have that new feel on the pedal, there's still a lot of travel before I stop what am I missing? I've never bled the brakes, replaced any calipers, the cylinder, or the booster, just pads and rotors throughout the years.

Comment: Four wheel disc or drums in the rear?

Comment: 4 wheel disc, I'll update my question when I get to my computer.

Comment: What's the year, make and model, and if you don't want to disclose, what's the brake fluid type? An 'old car' with four wheel disks - Porsche?

Comment: 2001 Buick Regal @Ehryk

Comment: GM HAS THIS PROBLEM...ITS FOUND IN GM ASTROS AS WELL...PLEASE CHECK WITH GM OR RECALL...TSB's and all info...it is a recall I believe...but not certain...

Comment: I agree with Paulster and AF7...I mis understood your delima at 1st...I was helping my friend with his Olds Alero brakes...2004...last year...disc front...rear shoe set up...dragging noise...he put a drum on it but noise still there...He has bonded shoes...I asked him to please get riveted for safety sake...he is cheeeep... I own a car he sold me in 2011...a rear shoe lost its lining (he put a half set on rear and I got towed home) I am now going to use all new Bosch shoes etc etc...both sides!!! Always google your issue and see some great advice and wrong advice as well...oh and my friend yak

Answer (score 6):

There are two things I can think of which may be the problem.

First - You could start by flushing the break lines with fresh brake fluid. Old fluid in the lines can contain water and air which would not be good and give you the squishy feeling. Getting rid of the old fluid would probably help the pedal feel tremendously. Ensure you are bleeding the brake lines correctly, starting from the furthest brake away from the master cylinder and working your way back. If you don't have a tool for brake bleeding (vacuum or pressure), this is a two person job.

Second - You may have a bulging soft line. These are the lines which attach to the calipers/wheel cylinders which allow for suspension travel and wheel turning. If there is a bulge in one of these, it could fail at any time, which is a very dangerous proposition. If this is the case, it is something which needs to be taken care of immediately.

Comment: This actually helped quite a bit, for future readers.

Answer (score 5):

First,
you need to change the brake fluid ASAP. This is an hygroscopic oil with an high boiling point. Even if you are not using the car, it slowly absorbs water and contaminants from small leaks and deterioration of the brake circuit. Water, having a low boiling point, will degrade the performance of the circuit up to making them very low. It is **mandatory** to change DOT4 brake fluid every 2 years. Efficient brakes are much more important than a new shiny paint job or whatever else done to your car.

If the brake feel is still unsatisfactory, you can try changing the rubber hoses going from the brake lines to the calipers with braided hose cables. These will in general inflate less under pressure and provide better feel and harder brake response. If this again fails to provide the feel you want from the brakes, a complete re-hauling of the braking system may be necessary.